# Running SL4A facade APIs from host python shell

Tags: python

Objective: 
Trying to run SL4A facade APIs from python shell on the host system (windows 7 PC)

My environment: 
1. On my windows 7 PC, i have python 2.6.2
2. Android sdk tools rev 21, platform tools rev 16
3. API level 17 supported for JB 4.2
4. I have 2 devices ( one running android 2.3.3 and another android 4.2.2) both running Python for android and SL4A

I'm trying these commands as specified at http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/RemoteControl

Here are the commands which i'm trying on the python shell:

Python 2.6.2 (r262:71605, Apr 14 2009, 22:40:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```
>>> import android  
>>> droid=android.Android  
>>> droid.makeToast("Hello")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: type object 'Android' has no attribute 'makeToast'

Before this i'm performing the port forwarding and starting a private server as shown below

```
$ adb forward tcp:9999 tcp:4321  
$ set AP_PORT=9999
```

Also set the server on the target listening on port 9999 ( through SL4A->preferences->serverport.

Please help to understand where i'm doing mistake which gives the above error while trying droid.makeToast("Hello") ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

> > > import android
> > >       droid=android.Android()
> > >       droid.makeToast("Hello")

(you are missing parentheses after android.Android)

Comment: William,i use a lower version of python (2.6.2), in which android.Android is the syntax, android.Android() throws syntax error. However when i tried on a ubuntu the makeToast is working. What i suspect is, port forwarding was not working on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you solved the problem. This is what I found, so maybe for somebody else it will be useful.
You need to run all your commands inside the DOS shell...otherwise you will get that error[11001].
If you still want to run you commands outside the DOS shell - add a new environment variable as described here:
http://www.smartphonedaq.com/installation.page